# Validate is excel column exist using JasperETL or Talend

Tags: excel, validation, talend

I'm new to JasperETL.

I want to import an Excel file to MS SQL server. 
Let say that i have an excel file with these columns (all columns are required):

- NAME_ID
- NAME
- SEX

I want to perform a validation to check if the excel file, given by the user has all the columns required?

Answer (score 0):

Talend will only read in the positional columns defined in the schema of an input delimited file so if your file contains three or more columns these first 3 will be read in as your defined schema.

Assuming you are happy with that then your next step is to simply enforce some schema definitions that match your SQL server database.

As a CSV is plain text I find it easiest to read all columns in as strings and then check the data types and lengths or precision using a tSchemaComplianceCheck component which will filter out rows that don't match the schema defined in the component. This then allows you to take some action on these invalid rows rather than just ignoring them which is what would happen if you defined a strict schema on your input component.

To check that all the columns are provided simply remove the nullable check box. You might also want to use a tFilterRow component to check for where each field is equal to `""` (blank).